# Не правильный вывод иерархического запроса

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть **иерархическая** таблица и еще 2 таблицы связанные с ним.

иерархическая таблица users

```
| id | parent_id | obj_id | obj_type |
--------------------------------------
| 1  |     null  |   1    |  agent   |
-------------------------------------- 
| 2  |      1    |   2    |  agent   |
-------------------------------------- 
| 3  |      1    |   1    | employee |
--------------------------------------
| 4  |      3    |   3    |  agent   |
--------------------------------------  
| 5  |      2    |   2    | employee |
--------------------------------------
| 6  |      4    |   4    |  agent   |
--------------------------------------  
| 7  |      5    |   3    | employee |
--------------------------------------
```

тут 2 типа `user`: `employee` и `agent`. Согласно есть 2 таблицы.

Таблица `employee`

```
| id | fullName  |
-----------------
| 1  |   Shynaz  |
-----------------
| 2  |    Oljas  |
-----------------
| 3  |   Erzhan  |  
-----------------
```

и таблица `agent`

```
| id |  name   |
----------------
| 1  | Shyngys |
----------------
| 2  |  Suha   |
----------------
| 3  |   Koja  |  
----------------
| 4  | Zhandos |  
----------------
```

Запрос не выводит полностью все записи. Таблицы намного упрощенные, но суть и ключевые поля те же.

**Запрос:**

```
WITH ChildNodes(id, name) 
    AS(
    SELECT 
       parent_de.id, 
       case parent_de.obj_type
        When 'agent' then (select l.Name from Agent l where l.ID = parent_de.obj_id)
        When 'employee' then (Select e.Fullname from employee e where e.ID = parent_de.obj_id)
       end as name
    FROM users parent_de
    left Join employee parent_e
        On parent_de.obj_id = parent_e.id and parent_de.obj_type = 'employee'
    left Join Agent parent_l 
        On parent_de.obj_id = parent_l.ID and parent_de.obj_type = 'agent'
    WHERE parent_de.parent_id = 1--- and parent_de.obj_type = 'employee'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
       child_de.id, 
       case child_de.obj_type
        When 'agent' then (select l.Name from Agent where l.ID = child_de.obj_id)
        When 'employee' then (Select e.Fullname from employee e where e.ID = child_de.obj_id)
       end as name
    FROM users child_de
     Inner Join employee child_e 
        On child_de.obj_id = child_e.id --and child_de.obj_type = 'employee' 
     Inner Join Agent child_l
        On child_de.obj_id = child_l.ID --and child_de.obj_type = 'agent'
     Inner JOIN ChildNodes parent ON parent.id = child_de.parent_id
     )

    SELECT 
    ChildNodes.id, 
    ChildNodes.name
    FROM ChildNodes
```

**Вопросы:**

1. Почему запрос не выводит полностью все `child` элементы?
2. Есть - ли другие способы вывода всех `child` элементов определенного элемента?

Comment: Во втором SELECT вы используете INNER JOIN, вместо LEFT JOIN для таблиц employee и agent. Думаю, в этом причина того, что не выводятся все записи.

Comment: @rogueCapella, Я не могу заменить INNER JOIN на LEFT JOIN вы ходит такая ошибка: `Outer join is not allowed in the recursive part of a recursive common table expression 'ChildNodes'`

Comment: Другой способ вывода child основан на создание рекурсивной пользовательской функции, но CTE быстрее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переписал ваш запрос: 
- вынес left join из CTE, так как там действительно нельзя его использовать
- избавился от CASE WHEN в пользу более очевидного решения

```
    WITH ChildNodes(id, obj_id) 
    AS(
        SELECT 
          parent_de.id, 
          parent_de.obj_id
        FROM users parent_de   
        WHERE parent_de.parent_id = 1--- and parent_de.obj_type = 'employee'

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
          child_de.id, 
          child_de.obj_id       
         FROM users child_de    
         Inner JOIN ChildNodes parent 
            ON parent.id = child_de.parent_id
     )

    SELECT 
       ChildNodes.id,
       case c.obj_type
          When 'agent' then (select l.Name from Agents l where l.ID = c.obj_id)
          When 'employee' then (Select e.Fullname from employees e where e.ID = c.obj_id)
       end as name
       --coalesce(child_e.fullName, child_l.name, '') as name
    FROM ChildNodes 
     left Join employee child_e 
        On ChildNodes.obj_id = child_e.id --and child_de.obj_type = 'employee' 
     Left Join agent child_l
        On ChildNodes.obj_id = child_l.id --and child_de.obj_type = 'agent'
```